# How to stop FFMPEG from running if connection to input stream is lost?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am capturing thumbnails from a webcam RTMP stream every 1 second to JPG files.  Here's my command line:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.89:554/11 -f image2 -r 1 thumb%03d.jpg
```

How can I make FFMPEG die with an error if the input RTMP stream is lost for a given timeout period?  Currently, if I lose connection to the webcam, FFMPEG starts throwing "Unknown error" messages, but when the network reconnects, ffmpeg appears to reconnect to the stream, but does not output any more captured frames.  I have to manually kill the process and restart it to again start capturing frames.

It would be nice to simply have ffmpeg die when it loses connection for a specific timeout period.  Then I could monitor the process and restart when it ends.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [ffmpeg timeout for RTSP](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp) :

> **timeout** Set maximum timeout (in seconds) to wait for incoming
>   connections.
>
> A value of -1 means infinite (default). This option implies the
>   rtsp_flags set to ‘listen’.
>
> **stimeout** Set socket TCP I/O timeout in
>   microseconds.

Comment: What about HTTP?

Comment: This is not an answer. The 'timeout' argument works when ffmpeg is acting as a server. As it says in your quote, "wait for incoming connections". The question is about the same functionality when ffmpeg is acting as an rtmp client.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is actually to put a timeout on the socket connection:

```
[...] -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 30000000 -i rtsp://192.168.1.89:554/11 [...]
```

(30 seconds in this case)